# regex to select after and upto specific character at same time

Tags: java, regex

Is there any way I could select specific text after specific text and keep selecting until that word is selected. And once selected then leave the remaining.

Here is the example

```
    ABCDEF
     JHJHJNJN<098978686
     <jjg>
    HGHJFGV XXXX    
       10-10-2018
    JHKGHKGHG
        JKHJHHJM
10-10-2019 JGHHGHGVH
HBVJHBHBB
```

Just want to select this date 10-10-2018 in whole content which always comes after XXX with couple of spaces. I can't use just regex with specific value(10-10-2018) because date can be changed and possible that date pattern somewhere is also present like in example in last line.

Please share your thoughts..!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the example is correct, then the following regex will extract just the date using `find()` and ensure that `DOTALL` is set.

```
"XXXX.*?[\\s]+([\\d]{1,2}-[\\d]{1,2}-[\\d]{4})"
```

Basically, search for XXX followed by spaces/newline then find the date. It will be placed into a group and can then be extracted.

You can see the operation [at this location](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyyjx5n4d), though be sure to select "DOTALL".

```
public String getDate(String input)
{
    String date = "";
    Pattern dte = Pattern.compile("XXXX.*?[\\s]+([\\d]{1,2}-[\\d]{1,2}-[\\d]{4})", Pattern.DOTALL);

    Matcher m = dte.matcher(input);
    if (m.find() && m.groupCount() > 0) {
        date = m.group(1);
    }

    return date;
}
```

Test case

```
@Test
public void testData() throws Exception
{
    RegEx_52879334 re = new RegEx_52879334();
    String input = re.getInputData();

    String date = re.getDate(input);

    assertEquals("10-10-2018", date);
    System.out.println("Found: " + date);
}
```

Output:

> Found: 10-10-2018